# PendingIntent with Extras return null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I'm trying to implement Notifications in my app.

I'm using AlarmManager with a PendingIntent of a intent with some Extras (Models Objects) but, when I Receive in a BroadcastReceiver class, all my extras disappear

Here's the code:
MainActivity

```
private void saveNotification(Task t) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", t.getTitle()); //not null object
    intent.putExtra("text", t.getText()); //not null object
    // intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); - I tried, but it didn't work
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 12345678, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "seting the notification in 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyAlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
        String taskTitle = bundle.getString("title"); //null here
        String taskText = bundle.getString("text"); // also null here
        startNotification(context, taskTitle , taskText);
    }
}
```

My guess is that the received intent in onReceive method may be not the original intent sended in the saveNotification method, but I have no ideia how to get the original one.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve the problem because I am suffering the same thing